# "Error: cannot allocate vector of size x kb" when loading R workspace

Tags: r

I am encountering an issue when attempting to load a 1.8GB workspace into RStudio. I receive a string of messages such as:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8 Kb

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 64 Kb

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16 Kb

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 256 Kb

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 32 Kb
```

etc.

The objects appear in my Global Environment but attempting to call them yields further errors such as those above.

In addition, my PC should have ample (>10GB) RAM for this workspace, but in Task Manager RAM usage is shown as ~80%.

I have tried:

1. Restarting everything
2. gc()
3. Using 64 bit version

I couldn't find any other solutions.

Many thanks

Comment: Is your pc always using > 80% ram or only when trying to load the workspace in R?

Comment: Only when I'm trying to load the workspace